# WARNING in [eslint] React Hook UseEffect has a missing dependency

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

This is the code

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Header from './../components/Header';

const SingleProduct = ({ match }) => {
  const [product, setProduct] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchproduct = async () => {
      const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/products/${match.params.id}`);
      setProduct(data);
    };
    fetchproduct();
  }, []);
```

and I keep getting this warning

```
WARNING in [eslint]
src\screens\SingleProduct.js
  Line 14:6:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'match.params.id'. Either include it or 
remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

I'm a beginner so I don't really know how to fix it

Comment: This answer is correct https://stackoverflow.com/a/75801062/528136 I think you are misunderstanding how useEffect work. It will not run on each re-render, only when its dependencies change. That’s why eslint complains.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your effect depends on the `match.params.id`, which was not present in the dependency array, adding it will solve the issue.

```js
 useEffect(() => {
    const fetchproduct = async () => {
      const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/products/${match.params.id}`);
      setProduct(data);
    };
    fetchproduct();
  }, [match.params.id]); // ADD HERE
```